# Connecting Python to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

So I was following a YT tutorial to authenticate using OAuth 2.0 in python. I got the following code:

```
import os
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.cloud import bigquery

client_file = 'some_text.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'

creds = None

if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', scopes=SCOPES)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_file, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port = 0)
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

service_bq = build('bigquery', 'v2' , credentials=creds)
```

The code works fine as I can authenticate my user, but now I need to create a connection to BigQuery to read, load, delete, update specific data from some tables. What are the next steps to follow? I search multiple tutorials and none of them are working.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already have a project on **Google Cloud Platform**, browse your console and `enable Billing for your project and the BigQuery API`. You also have to [create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-create#creating) for the `credentials`: `GCP > IAM and Admin > Service Accounts`

Select your newly created service account and go to `Keys > Add key`. You will need the **json key file** for the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

You will also need a `BigQuery Client Library`. You can go through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) to help you set up for BigQuery API.

You can also visit these links for references: [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest) and [[2]](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html).

I also found an SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988362/google-oauth-2-0-using-python-for-gcp-bigquery) related to your case.